# Swiper init after AJAX call is wrong

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, swiper.js

I have a Swiper in a separate HTML-File called `scrollyteller.html`:

```
<section class="scrollyteller">
    <div class="swiper-container">

        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
           <!-- Slides here -->
        <div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The reason why I have this in a separate file is, that this swiper has some complex animations and a lot of assets which i don't wanna load everytime the user visits the website. The Swiper later will be triggered by a click on a link withing the navigation.

So I have an `index.html` that loads a `script.js` with all the required functions to initialize the swiper. The function to initialize the swiper is called `initScrolly()`.

I also have a button on the `index.html` that initialized the `XMLHttpRequest` to get the `scrollyteller.html`.

The following is the script to get the html-file and append it to the `index.html`:

```
.....click function on button:

                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {

                        var parsedResult = parser.parseFromString(xhr.response, "text/html"),
                            html = parsedResult.querySelector('body').innerHTML;

                        container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

                        container.style.display = "block";

                        initScrolly();

                    }
                };

            xhr.open('GET', url);

            xhr.send();
```

I call `initScrolly()` at the end of the AJAX call but it seems like the DOM is not ready from the `scrollyteller.html`. Cause Swiper calculates wrong heights (like 126123px....) and the pagination bullets aren't initialized either. Once I resize my window the Swiper works just fine. So it must be the DOM (?).

Those are the swiper settings:

```
var settings = {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    paginationClickable: false,
    mousewheelControl: true,
    simulateTouch: false,
    speed: 1000,
    effect: 'fade',
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    direction: 'vertical',
    onPaginationRendered: function(){
        if (!rendered) {
            initBullets(scrollyteller);
        }
        rendered = true;
    },
    onImagesReady: function() {

        if (!loaded) {
            //remove loader only when images are loaded;

            TweenMax.to(loader, 1, {
                opacity: 0, onComplete: function () {
                    loader.style.display = "none";
                    TweenMax.to(scrollyWrapper, 2, {opacity: 1});
                }
            });
        }
        loaded = true;
    }
};
```

When I open the `scrollyteller.html` on it's own, everything is working fine. It's just not working with the AJAX.

So the question really is, how do I make sure the DOM is ready before I call `initScrolly()` ?

I have tried to put a `<script>` tag at the end of the `scrollyteller.html` but that didn't really work either as the script is not evaluated on it's own. and evaluating the script inside the AJAX-Call results in the same problem as just calling the function.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!